# how to make a form field of type List<Inventory> for camunda rest api

Tags: java, forms, camunda

We're going to build a workflow management system and We're embedding the camunda engine Rest API into our Rest Application.

Now I have Inventory defined like this:

```
public class Inventory {
    private String objectName;
    private int objectCount;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and this is a sample workflow:
[image]

in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="1.11.3">
  <bpmn:process id="test" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1v6clcy</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1v6clcy" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="testtask" />
    <bpmn:userTask id="testtask" name="testtask" camunda:formKey="testform">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:formData>
          <camunda:formField id="inventories" label="name" type="List&#60;org.example.Inventory&#62;" />
        </camunda:formData>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1v6clcy</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_07kdfp4</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:userTask>
    <bpmn:endEvent id="EndEvent_0vm605w">
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_07kdfp4</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_07kdfp4" sourceRef="testtask" targetRef="EndEvent_0vm605w" />
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="test">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="173" y="102" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_1v6clcy_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_1v6clcy">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="209" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="275" y="120" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="242" y="99" width="0" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="UserTask_1s01hea_di" bpmnElement="testtask">
        <dc:Bounds x="275" y="80" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="EndEvent_0vm605w_di" bpmnElement="EndEvent_0vm605w">
        <dc:Bounds x="439" y="109" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="412" y="149" width="90" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_07kdfp4_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_07kdfp4">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="375" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="407" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="407" y="127" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="439" y="127" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="377" y="117.5" width="90" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

I'll eventually have a html form which will submit something like this:

```
{ 
    "inventories" : [{"name": "banana","count": 3},{"name":"orange","count": 4}]
}
```

I want to submit this to /task/{id}/submit-form but I don't know what to put as type.

I tried putting the type in modeler as `List<org.example.Inventory>` but the rest api throws an exception when deploying the process definition like this:

> org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors: 
>   * unknown type 'List' | org.example/PM.bpmn | line 65 | column 90

I've seen [this](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/usertask/task-form-embedded-serialized-java-object) example as well but I'm only using the Rest API not the whole bpm platform(besides we prefer to have pure html forms).

So how to do it ? what should I put in type ?

my camunda.cfg.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">

        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
        <property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUsername" value="sa" />
        <property name="jdbcPassword" value="" />

        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

my processengineprovider:

```
public class MyProcessEngineProvider implements ProcessEngineProvider {
    @Override
    public ProcessEngine getDefaultProcessEngine() {
        ProcessEngine engine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
        RepositoryService repositoryService = engine.getRepositoryService();
        repositoryService.createDeployment()
                .addClasspathResource("org.newtech/PM.bpmn")
                .deploy();            
        return engine;
    }

    @Override
    public ProcessEngine getProcessEngine(String s) {
        return getDefaultProcessEngine();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getProcessEngineNames() {
        Set<String> names = new HashSet<>(1);
        names.add("default");
        return names;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @aleksaRazer22 We actually settled on setting just the form key without any form fields, As for storing List of objects the solution was storing them as Json variables using Spin plugin